# Add to dictionary with an f-string inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, f-string

I'm currently trying to do something very similar to:

```py
for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c']: 
    key1 = f'{letter}_1' 
    key2 = f'{letter}_2' 
    numbers = { 
        key1: 1, 
        key2: 2 
    }
```

I would expect `numbers` to be: `{'a_1': 1, 'a_2': 2, 'b_1': 1, 'b_2': 2, 'c_1': 1, 'c_2': 2}`. Instead I get: `{'c_1': 1, 'c_2': 2}`.

How can I go about producing the former?

Comment: You're re-initialising the dictionary within the loop. You need to declare the dictionary outside of the loop and then add values to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you did not initialise the dict before the `for` loop.

```
numbers = {}


for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    key1 = f'{letter}_1'
    key2 = f'{letter}_2'
    numbers.update ({
        key1: 1,
        key2: 2
    })

print(numbers)
```

Comment: Ah that's it. I had tried initialising previously, but that doesn't fix it by itself. The `numbers.update` was the key I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this

```
numbers = {}
for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    key1 = f'{letter}_1' 
    key2 = f'{letter}_2' 
    numbers.update({ 
        key1: 1, 
        key2: 2 
    })
```

You need to initialize your dictionary outside the for-loop. In your code, you're creating a new dictionary with each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new object every loop.

```
numbers = {}

for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c']: 
    key1 = f'{letter}_1' 
    key2 = f'{letter}_2' 
    numbers.update({ 
        key1: 1, 
        key2: 2 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, if desired, build it with a dict comprehension as:

```
mydict = {f'{x}_{str(y)}':y for x in ['a','b','c'] for y in (1,2)}
```

Which gives:

```
{'a_1': 1, 'a_2': 2, 'b_1': 1, 'b_2': 2, 'c_1': 1, 'c_2': 2}
```

It's a bit hard to read but not too bad.

Comment: That's a nice one-liner. Unfortunately my actual usage has a few extra steps in the loop that would blow this up into full unreadable territory.